# Bash script not working due to path C:\Program Files (x86)... in Windows

Tags: bash, shell-script, windows, quoting

I am developing a bash script in Windows 7 using a bash emulated terminal, exactly I use bash terminal in MobaXterm 9.1. The reason is that I have a Windows 7 laptop but my script would eventually run on a Jenkins Linux Server.

Spaces and/or ( in path are preventing my script from running successfully.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
eclexe0="C:\Program Files (x86)\HPCCSystems\6.0.4\clienttools\bin\ecl.exe"
eclexe1="/drives/c/Program Files (x86)/HPCCSystems/6.0.4/clienttools/bin/ecl.exe"
clear

#1
echo "Testing if ecl.exe is available..."
if [ -f "$eclexe0" ]; then
  echo "FOUND." >&2
else
  echo "NOT FOUND." >&2
  exit 1
fi

echo "Executing ecl.exe"

echo 1
eval "$eclexe0"

echo 2
```

When I run it the output is

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see script is not happy with path *C:\Program Files (x86)*. If I move files to another path (C:\oscar\eclfolder) it works. I tried the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters?newreg=7619c8933d2f4cdcbf43242e9a823bce) but they don't work, probably because I am in a Windows 7...

How can I make this script work?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` ?  You _should_ just be able to do `"$eclexe0"`.

Comment: What is your "bash emulated terminal"? Where could I (legally) get a copy of it? (I can't reproduce this under Cygwin.)

Comment: MobaXterm is free if you want to install it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't work because you are running `eval` on the pathname to the executable file.

In any shell script, you can already use a variable to specify a command to run.

If you don't quote your `$variable` reference, the contents of the variable will also be split into separate words according to whitespace.

You have quoted your variable reference.  However, by running `eval`, you are parsing the result of the variable expansion a *second* time.  You don't need to.

The following illustration may be instructive:

```
$ ls
file.txt    file2.txt
$ somevar=ls
$ $somevar
file.txt    file2.txt
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 Me  staff  0 Sep  2 16:06 file.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Me  staff  0 Sep  2 16:06 file2.txt
$ somevar='ls -l'
$ $somevar
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 Me  staff  0 Sep  2 16:06 file.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Me  staff  0 Sep  2 16:06 file2.txt
$ "$somevar"
bash: ls -l: command not found
$
```

As you can see, when I attempt to run `"ls -l"`, quoted, the shell looks for a command with that *exact* name—spaces included.

In my example, that's not what I want.

However, in your example, that *is* what you want.

Instead of using `eval "$eclexe0"`, just use `"$eclexe0"`.

---

**The Bigger Picture**

Free advice: If you plan to run your script on a Linux box, test it on a Linux box.  MobaXterm is not a Linux box.

Install Vagrant and VirtualBox (which are both free) and create a virtual machine you can do your tests in.

---

Further reading:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)
- [The Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to escape the quotes like this ( "\"string"\" ) according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253782/bash-problem-with-eval-variables-and-quotes

Comment: It would be better simply to avoid using `eval` in the first place. Unless it's got a _magic extension_ provided by this "bash terminal emulator" it's not needed in the code given by the OP.